# Create a DirectX staging texture backed by a custom RAM allocation

Tags: directx, textures, driver

I am the author of Looking Glass (https://looking-glass.io) and I am looking for a way to improve our DXGI Desktop Duplication capture performance. This question is specifically about how to avoid an extra CPU memory copy as part of our pipeline.

If you are not familiar with Looking Glass, what we are doing is using a virtual hardware device (IVSHMEM) to map a block of shared memory into a Windows Virtual Machine. We then use this shared RAM to pass the captured desktop back to the host so that it can be rendered on screen. We do this so that we can acquire the video output of a GPU that has been passed through to the guest by means of VFIO and integrate it into the Linux desktop.

Currently, our pipeline works as follows:

1. `AcquireNextFrame`
2. `CopyResource` to staging texture (system RAM)
3. `mmap` staging texture
4. `memcpy` to IVSHMEM memory
5. `unmap` staging texture

Is it possible to avoid this extra copy by creating a DX11 staging texture backed by the IVSHMEM device directly, removing the need to copy the texture again?

Ie:

1. `AcquireNextFrame`
2. `CopyResource` to texture backed by IVSHMEM ram.

If this needs to be done in kernel space (the IVSHMEM driver) this is possible, but it would be preferable if there is a userspace method of performing this.

Note, the IVSHMEM device is simply a dumb virtual device that provides the shared memory as one of its base address registers (BARs).

Edit: for reference here is the existing code we are using:
https://github.com/gnif/LookingGlass/blob/master/host/platform/Windows/capture/DXGI/src/dxgi.c

Comment: Why do you copy from GPU to CPU, then from CPU to CPU? You can copy from the acquired frame to a GPU texture readable from CPU, map that texture to get a CPU pointer and copy to where you want.

Comment: The second CPU to CPU copy is to move the texture data into the virtual IVSHMEM device so it's accessible outside the virtual machine. The first copy to GPU texture readable by CPU is a copy to system ram, see the MS docs on the staging texture.

Comment: Yes, I got that; can't you copy from a CPU RAM pointer to IVSHMEM memory?

Comment: `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` - A resource that supports data transfer (copy) from the GPU to the CPU. This is what we are already doing, this staging texture is system ram allocated by DirectX. We are copying this directly to IVSHMEM after mmap. mmap is the trigger to copy this to system RAM.

Comment: You don't understand what I meant. You don't need staging, you can map a GPU texture to a RAM pointer (if that GPU is accessible by CPU).

Comment: Can you provide a small example/sample? I believe we are actually talking about the same thing here. I added a link to the existing implementation of what we are doing.

Comment: @SimonMourier I think I get what you're saying. I can just map the texture that AcquireNextFrame provides directly? IIRC I tried this but it was quite some time ago and I may have had other issues as I was learning the API still.

Comment: Not sure the acquired frame is CPU readable. Sorry I wasn't clear. Your step 2) should already be GPU to GPU, and if you created that texture with read access, you can get a RAM pointer and copy to IVSHMEM memory (I'm not sure how that works). That would already be 1 GPU->GPU copy and 1 GPU->CPU copy. Doing better than that would mean stay in the GPU, but DXGI is only a user-space API.

Comment: Just tested this, the acquired frame is not CPU readable. Profiling suggests that step 2 is actually a GPU to system ram transfer which is what I am aiming to remove/improve if at all possible. Or some other way to get the GPU to DMA the texture directly into IVSHMEM.